# How do i customize a resourceful route in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails the default path for a post 'show' action would be `/post/:id`. 
How do I change it something like `/post/:pid`?

I have read about overriding the `to_param` method

```
def to_param
  self.pid
end
```

That makes passing the pid of the post instance, but it would be available in the action as
params[:id] which is not apt.

What I would like is `params[:pid]` in any action would give me the pid of the post instance.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is it necessary that you need to keep this as a Resourceful route?  If you are making these customizations, a custom route seems appropriate.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url have u ever see it

Comment: The link tells to override the to_param method. I had mentioned about that in my post - but i would like to know if it is possible to do this in the action -  pid  = params[:pid] rather than pid = params[:id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put this in the routes:

```
match "/post/:pid" => "post#show"
```

Comment: Can i do that if i want this as a resourceful route.

Comment: Put this line before your resourceful routes for Post. Rails will pick up the one that matched first from the routes.